# Is "." really an allowed wildcard character for _wfopen_s/_wfindfirst?

Tags: c, winapi, file-io

I have some weird behavior on my Win32-System: If I pass the path `C:/temp/file.txt.` to `_wfindfirst` and `_wfopen_s`, I get a successfully opened file although only `C:/temp/file.txt` exists on disk.

First, I thought that the `.` could also be an accepted wild card character on Win32, but looking at the Microsoft docs

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690414(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true

these don't mention the `.` character at all.

Of course, I could check the path before putting it into `_wfopen_s` or `_wfindfirst`, but I'm wondering if there are other means to prevent me from opening files with illegeal paths...

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe with `_wfopen_s( &f, L"c:/temp/file.abc .txt", L"rb");`  I get an `ENOENT` (2) returned even though `c:/temp/file.abc.txt` exists. Can you show the exact code you use for that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: could be the case that some modifications in my code caused that behavior. Removing Edit. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While NTFS itself supports periods at the end of a filename (and certain clients, like the old POSIX subsystem, can use such files), the Win32 API itself doesn't and will strip off a trailing `'.'` when opening a file:

> - [INFO: Filenames Ending with Space or Period Not Supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115827)
>
> CreateFile() removes trailing spaces and periods from file and directory names. This is done for compatibility with the FAT and HPFS file systems.

Apparently, `FindFirstFile()` and friends do the same (not too surprising given the above, but I can't find any explicit docs saying so).

Instead of checking the input filename directly to see if it matches one of your restricted filenames, you can check the `name` field of the `_wfinddata_t` structure returned by `_wfindfirst()` to see if it matches (and do the same for all files found by that and `_wfindnext()`). But I guess this was where you were going.

Keep in mind that passing in an 8.3 format filename might also return a rather different filename in the `name` field (because of the mapping that the OS does for long filenames to short filenames).  you might need to take that mapping into consideration in your checks, and the Win32 `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` APIs might give you help with that since they return both the long and any corresponding short filename for a match.

If you use `FindFirstFileW()` directly instead of `_wfindfirst()` you can check the `cFileName` and cAlternatefileName` fields to see what file was actually found

Comment: +1 for having an explation handy that tells **why** the behavior is that way!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a wildcard. Dot at the end of the filename is always omitted, so `F.` and `F` are equivalent for all `F`.

Comment: So, if I want to prevent opening such files, I have to manage it by hand?

Comment: @eckes: What do you want to prevent, really? Dot at the end simply has no meaning and can be ignored.

Comment: If some weird guys pass in a path with a dot at the end to my web server, I'm not willing to give them a valid file if there is none...

Comment: @eckes: If there's no file `F`, then there's no file `F.`.

Comment: Yep. But there **is** `F` and I won't return `F` when `F.` was requested... Just noticed that `_wfopen_s` also ignores spaces in the path (i.e. `C:/temp/file.abc.txt` gets opened when `C:/temp/file.abc .txt` is requested). This is ridiculous!

Comment: Anyone care to provide a citation showing that F. and F are indeed equivalent for all F using _wfindfirst under Windows?